# C++ - overload structure dereference operator and use it in unique_ptr

Tags: c++, smart-pointers, dereference

I have one implementation class and one wrapper class, and I want to access to implementation class instance through wrapper class with structure dereference (->) operator. So far, no problem.

```cpp
class Implementation
{
  public:
    doSomething();
}

class Wrapper
{
  public:
    Implementation* operator->() {
      return _implPtr.get();
    }
  private:
    std::shared_ptr<Implementation> _implPtr;
}
```

It works when I use it like below:

```cpp
Wrapper wrapper;
wrapper->doSomething();
```

But when I use the wrapper class with unique_ptr, compiler throws an error:

```cpp
auto wrapper = std::make_unique<Wrapper>();
wrapper->doSomething();
```

The error is "'class Wrapper' has no member named 'doSomething'".

How can I access to the implementation class in this scenario?

Comment: `_implPtr->get();` -- Shouldn't that be `_implPtr.get();`?

Comment: You can’t. `unique_ptr` adds an indirection — by design! Your code also doesn’t work with a `Wrapper*` object, for the same reason. Use `(*wrapper)->doSomething`.

Comment: The shown code is obviously not the real code with the compilation error, so any speculation as to the cause of the compilation error will be nothing more than speculation, and a random guess.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie yes, my mistake while summarising

Comment: @SamVarshavchik I can't share the real code since the real classes are huge and I'm not allowed to share them

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`std::unique_ptr` (and `std::shared_ptr`) has its own [`operator->`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr/operator*) to return the pointer it is holding.

Your failing code is essentially doing this:

```cpp
auto wrapper = std::make_unique<Wrapper>();
//wrapper->doSomething();
Wrapper *ptr = wrapper.operator->();
ptr->doSomething(); // ERROR!
```

Indeed, there is no `doSomething()` method in your `Wrapper` class.

To do what you are attempting, you need to dereference the `Wrapper*` pointer to access the actual `Wrapper` object, then you can call its own `operator->` to access its `Implementation*` pointer, eg:

```cpp
auto wrapper = std::make_unique<Wrapper>();
(*wrapper)->doSomething();
```

Which is basically doing this:

```cpp
auto wrapper = std::make_unique<Wrapper>();
//(*wrapper)->doSomething();
Wrapper &ref = wrapper.operator*();
Implementation *impl = ref.operator->();
impl->doSomething(); // OK!
```